# How to drag annotation pin in ios like in Android?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, annotations, mapkit

In my application I am able to drag annotation from one point to other, but I want make the dragging as in Android i.e. when we select the annotation it will move a bit up and once the dragging ends it will come to its actual end point position by moving down.

I want to get the same kind of animation feel in iOS, can anybody suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733564/drag-an-annotation-pin-on-a-mapview

Comment: I could able to drag the pin, but my requirement is I should be able to drag it like the Android way.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it ...

MKPinkAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];

pin.animatesDrop = YES;
pin.canShowCallout = YES;
pin.draggable = YES;`

continue your coding from there forth

or you can go threw this link

https://github.com/yury/TiMobile-map-pin-drag-and-drop